# как напечатать что-то без лишней строки в питоне

Tags: python

хочу распечатать список без лишней пустой строки как:

```
["bin"]
['sdff"]
```

а не так:

```
["bin"]
['sdff"]\n
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) имеет параметр `end`, который по умолчанию равен переводу строки. Вы можете переопределить его пустой строкой.

***Пример:***

```py
print('First', end='')
print('Second')
```

***stdout:***

```py
FirstSecond
```

Comment: мне не нужно печатать в одной линии, а как в примере